# Scalar product of eigenstates of $\hat{S}_z$ and $\hat{S}_x$ operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Suppose that $|s_z\rangle$ and $|s_x\rangle$ are eigenvectors of operators $\hat{S}_z$ and $\hat{S}_x$ correspondingly, with $s_z$ and $s_x$ being eigenvalues. Is there a known formula for the scalar product $\langle s_x|s_z\rangle$? Spin $1/2$ case is trivial. Spin $1$ case is simple enough to express $|s_x\rangle$ vectors as linear combinations of $|s_z\rangle$ vectors and to find this scalar product directly. What about the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general case is given by rotating the z-axis to the x-axis by $\pi/2$ around the y-axis. The matrices which achieve that in the spherical basis are Wigner's celebrated [*d* rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#List_of_d-matrix_elements) where you plug in $\theta=-\pi /2$ (but beware of my signs, not fully guaranteed!).

Thus, for any spin *s*, 
$$
\langle s_x|= \langle s_z | e ^{-i(\pi/2) \hat S_y}~, \\
\langle s_x|s_z\rangle= d^s_{s_x ~ s_z} (-\pi/2) ~.
$$

So, e.g., in Feynman vIII, 7-12 , you get $\langle +|+\rangle=\langle + | -\rangle = 1/\sqrt 2$ for spin 1/2, and you may work out for spin 2 that $\langle 2| 1\rangle = 1/2\sqrt 2  $ , etc... Note the interchange identities for *d* at the end of that section.

Comment: Thank you very much! For my work, I need these formulas for spin $2$ and spin $5/2$. So your answer solves the problem.